# Madlibs jquery story game

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I was hoping someone could help me figure out what I need to start this. I'm making a mad libs game to where once you select an answer you scroll to the next part of the story with new answers based on the answer you gave for the previous section.

The full paragraph gets updated after each answer
There once was a ______ who was dreaming of the perfect bike to ride ______. She imagined ______, with warm sun reflecting on the spokes of the bike as she pedaled. She was ______, and knew the ride perfectly fit her size and style because ______. Now all she needed was ______ and here dream would be complete.

Here is what I currently have. The issue I'm running into is how to structure my data. Should I be looping through all questions and match values based on what you select.. should I have 4 gender objects with each specific question to that gender inside of it? How should I be updating the answers in each step.

http://jsfiddle.net/visualbam/gnwgzhye/1/

```
There once was a _____

A. Little boy
B. Little girl
C. Woman
D. Man
```

Then if you answered woman, the next part would be:

```
who was dreaming of the perfect bike to ride

A. to her daily job
B. on the beach
C. on trails
```

Comment: Make an effort. Come back when you hit a snag. The jQuery docs are awesome and should give you some good ideas.

Comment: I updated with my fiddle and a more specific question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better if you have a specific question, with things you've tried first, but here's a general outline of one way to accomplish this.

1. Create different arrays for the different types of answers you'll need (ie. an array for nouns, one for adjectives, etc.)

   `var nouns = ["car", "bus", "pizza"];`
2. Decide how to choose what options to give the user. You can choose a random subset at each point, you can manually specify what options to choose, you can create a dependency graph so that different earlier answers will lead to different later answers, etc.
3. Have some way of choosing an option at each point. This could be an HTML select box or some other method of your choosing. When an option is chosen, insert it into the paragraph at the correct point.

And that should basically be it.

Comment: I ended up using handlebars to load in the answers I needed via ajax and storing the answer clicked in a variable and appending it to a story div so it would update as they scrolled through.

http://jsfiddle.net/visualbam/gnwgzhye/3/